# Run a MySQL server in a self-contained folder

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I've seen many questions about how to run multiple sql servers on one server, but I would like to run mysqld as a user-level process and completely self contained in a folder (I have no permissions outside my user folder).

I spent some time using the --defaults-file=my.cnf, but it still seems to conflict with the system-level mysql server that's running.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to chroot MySQL - I'd love to say no problem, but that's not the case. It's a moody beast and it doesn't like to be jailed in chroot :P

Chroot instructions will vary between operating systems or even distributions, but here you go:

https://blackdown.de/articles/chrooting-recent-mysql-versions-on-debian-and-ubuntu/

http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/securing-mysql-step-step

if you need more just search mysql chroot + your distro name

Comment: chroot seems to be a sysadmin command, and I don't have permissions to use it, since I could supposedly use it to gain root access; any other way? I'm trying to do this as a user with no permissions

Comment: Use `fakechroot` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out http://mysqlsandbox.net/ .  I use it for running various sandbox instances on my laptop to test different versions of mysql.  It seems to run OK from just my homedir, but I have not tested running a sandbox with another mysqld instance on the same box.  Should probably run alright, since it allocates a non-standard port but you should be careful.